# Should I use a native or a hybrid app for an an app based Online-Shop

Tags: javascript, android, css, ios, hybrid-mobile-app

I want to make an app were users can buy different products. I don't want that the app runs in the browser. That's why I would user a native or a hybrid app. The Shop has a lot of products with a lot of images and I want that the images were load from a web storage in the app.

Is this possible with an native app or should I use a hybrid? Or it is even possible?

Which programming language do I need for a hybrid app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native vs Hybrid App debate is a one which varies its outcome based on your priorities. You should always go for whatever best suits your needs. Some points to consider while choosing to go with Native or Hybrid are,

1. **Development Time** -
   The foremost pointer to consider while Native vs Hybrid comparison is that the code is written individually for both Android and iOS platforms due to their technical variations in the former approach.
   Whereas in case of Hybrid, a single code is written for both the platforms by the same developers which means you can build Hybrid apps for Android and iOS using the same codes.
2. **Mobile App Cost** -
   As per the top mobile app development companies, app development with Hybrid approach can reduce the cost by 30%-35% when compared to that of Native app development for the same app project.
3. **UI/UX Experience/Performance** -
   Even though Hybrid apps have caught up with their Native counter parts in terms of performance, Native apps still deliver a much better experience and also provide a good long term stability.
4. **API and Third Party Library Support** -
   When it comes to API accessibility, the Native app development frameworks can use all the types of APIs directly. Whereas, the same is not possible in the case of Hybrid technology.

Now answering your specific queries, Image caching is available in both Native as well as Hybrid Apps and shouldn't be something you need to worry about too much.

You can go with either React Native or Flutter for building Hybrid Apps. React Native uses good old Javascript for development and Flutter uses a new language called Dart. Even though both are quite popular development frameworks, which one to choose is another debate in itself as both have their pros and cons.

Personally speaking, If I was building an eCommerce App, I would probably go with React Native.